# Комбинация одного масива в другом

Tags: массивы, математика

[image: Примерный перебор]

Нужен алгоритм который переберет все возможные значения масива N з размером тем же что и масивом 1111
в масиве [1111]
Нужны все значения от [1111] ..... [11N1] ....[1N1N]...[NNN1] .... до [NNNN]
Размер масива 1 может быть большим меньшим

Comment: Замените все N нулем - получите все числа от 0 до 15. Намек ясен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вам нужно перебрать комбинации с всего двумя элементами, можно воспользоваться как маской двоичными числами — так вы автоматически получите комбинации из нулей и единиц, в которых цифры можно будет заменить на нужные символы.

Запускаете цикл со счётчиком от нуля до нужного размера, число счётчика превращаете в строку в двоичном представлении, добавляете недостающие вначале нули, а потом меняете нули и единицы на любые нужные элементы. В вашем случае начальный `0` меняем на конечный `1`, а начальный `1` на конечный `N` (только в обратном порядке, чтобы не перепутались начальные и конечные единицы).

```js
const array = [];

for (let i = 0b0000; i <= 0b1111; i++) {
  array.push(
    i.toString(2)
      .padStart(4, 0)
      .replaceAll('1', 'N')
      .replaceAll('0', '1')
  );
}

console.log(array);
```